how to add a step to break out of long jenkins job
I have a long multi step (non pipeline) Jenkins job that i want to debug.
I don't want all the steps to activate until i've tested the first steps.
Is there a way of adding a temporary "break/stop" step to force it to exit early on?

as a work-a-round i just created an ant step targeting a non existent "DUMMY_STOP". this was good enough for my purposes, just stoping the script at a desired location.
